how to add my custom menu in the DocumentMap tab within the Navigation Pane in MS word

I would like to develop a custom menu using C# and VSTO. When I select "Yellow,button" the text of the heading1 (e.g., "Summary") in the image will change to yellow. Could you provide some idea? I'm uncertain whether Microsoft has provided relevant APIs, or if I need to use reverse engineering methods to achieve my goal. under "show Heading Leavels" button ，I want to add my customize button.
